# How to edit iWeb 09 Blog Template?

Tags: xml, iweb

In iWeb '09, I am trying to edit the Blog entry template, and can't figure out how to remove the picture from the template.  Ideally, I do not want the default placeholder picture to be present on the new entry template when I click the "Add Entry" button.

In the Blog.xml file (found under templateFileName/Shared/), it seems that the information regarding the Entries template (and specifically, the placeholder image) is around line 5133.

Answer (score 1):

Chris,
A non-coding solution to your problem is to not use the "Add Entry" button and instead create a duplicate of your previous post (assuming it has the layout you desire).  To accomplish this all you have to do is control-click (or right-click) the Title of a post on the Entries page and then select "Duplicate".  It will do a complete copy of the selected post and set the date to current date.  Then all you have to do is modify the title and delete the body text.  No more template defaults to deal with.

I could look into modifying templates in '09, but perhaps this is an acceptable solution without headaches.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks David.  I did end up doing this - it seems easy enough just to duplicate the last entry... not the most elegant solution, but it does work.  Just wish Apple would make it a little easier to edit templates in iWeb.